# How to generate a Cognos report for different email receiver?

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

How to generate a Cognos report for different email receiver?
I've a report need to send to different people. The difference of each report is the background picture of it which has the receiver's email address on it. On the other words, how to get the receiver email address when generate a report and make it as a part of content.

Comment: Seems odd to show the report reader their own email address.  For example, I already know my email address, so I don't need to see it on a report.  How does this information add value to the report?

Comment: Have you tried report bursting? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.doc/t_cr_rptstd_modrep_bursting_reports.html

Comment: Do you have access to Framework Manager?

Comment: If  I send you a report (.pdf)  which has your name on it. Then  I search the report in the internet and found it , I could know who leaks it and start an investigation(start from you).  Not odd at  all.  :)

Comment: There's no way to know who leaked it.  If they are going to leak it, they'd be pretty dense if they didn't open it with Adobe Acrobat and remove their name first.

Comment: Perhaps your need isn't to have the recipient's name as a watermark.  Maybe you need to be able to identify who leaked a document.  That's a completely different question.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/295009    how to get  CAMUsername  in a report and show it?

Comment: Yes, that's a completely different question. Tracing who leaks it is much more difficult. Adding user information in watermark is simple ,The question is how to get user information in report. :)

Answer (score 0):

To generate reports for other users you would use bursting in combination with triggering.

There is a trigger.sh in the `<CA-installdir>/webapps/utilities/trigger/trigger.sh`, where you pass triggers "xyz", which then fires the report execution.

Using this as starting point you might want to look at `<CA-installdir>/sdk/java/Scheduler/NewScheduler.java` to create schedules dynamically.

We have used the combination of trigger.sh + schedule to run +50k reports/month as billing overview to clients and save them into folders where only the specific client has access.

Setting the watermark as picture or text can be achieved by using a macro in your data query:

1. Create a query
2. Add a new data item and set expression to `#sq($account.defaultName)#`

You could also use `account.personalInfo.givenName` or `account.personalInfo.userName`